# Compile a library that uses mpi (AGMG)

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to compile the library [AGMG](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~ynotay/AGMG/).

The make file for the parallel example is looking like this:

```
# MPIopt    = -I/... (where to find mpif.h)
# MUMPSPopt = -I/... (where to find files to be included by 
#                     applications using MUMPS)
# MUMPSlib  = -l...  (link reference for MUMPS)
# SCALAP    = -l...  (link reference for SCALAPACK, needed by MUMPS)
# BLASLAPACK= -l...  (link reference for LAPACK & BLAS)
# MPIlib    = -l...  (link reference for MPI)
```

On my Debian mpif.h is found:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h 
/usr/lib/openmpi/include/mpi.h
```

So I wrote in the Makefile:

```
MPIopt  =   -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/
MPIlib    = -lmpi
```

But never the less, when I try to compile, I get the following errors:

```
:~/AGMG_3.0/Example_par$ make
cd ../SRC;make dpar
make[1]: Entering directory `AGMG_3.0/SRC'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `dpar'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `AGMG_3.0/SRC'
gfortran-4.4 -O4 -o Example_par Example_par.o ../SRC/dagmg_par.o   -lmpi 
Example_par.o: In function `MAIN__':
Example_par.f90:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `mpi_init_'
....
....
....
dagmg_par.f90:(.text+0x19fc9): undefined reference to `mpi_comm_rank_'
dagmg_par.f90:(.text+0x19fdd): undefined reference to `mpi_comm_size_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Example_par] Error 1
```

I'm quite confused by now, I had tries that succeeded, but than I had problems with scaplap
and the other requirements.
scalap is found:

```
$ dpkg -L libscalapack-mpi-dev 
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libscalapack-openmpi.a
```

mumps is found in /usr/lib/libsmumps.a and the header files are in /usr/include/smumps_c.h

So how do I put all this together?

I know that for a more advanced fortran or C developer this would be trivial ...

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
I'm putting here the full Makefile definitions, in hope it might help others:

```
MPIopt = -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -pthread 
MPIlib = -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 -lmpi 
MUMPSPopt = -I/usr/lib/libsmumps.a -I/usr/lib/libdmumps.a
MUMPSlib = -lsmumps  -ldmumps
BLASLAPACK=-L/usr/lib -llapack -lblas 
BLASLAPACK=-L/usr/lib -llapack -lblas 
SCALAP = -L/usr/lib/libscalapack-openmpi.a -lscalapack-openmpi

F90=gfortran-4.6
```

This builds it. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are linker errors.  It looks like your include files have been picked up successfully, but the linker is not seeing the MPI library.  Try changing `MPIlib    = -lmpi` to something that includes the path to `libmpi.a`, such as `MPIlib    = -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi`

Alternatively, try using the MPI compiler wrappers, as suggested by @haraldkl.  These should take care of linking to MPI automatically.

Comment: Thanks! This showed me how to do it! -L/Path/to/Library.a -llibName!

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing the fortran MPI library stuff. You should use the mpi compiler wrapper of your installation, usually it is called *mpif90*. If you want to specify all the libraries by hand you can have a glance at the options set by the wrapper with

```
mpif90 --showme
```

(for openmpi) or some similar flag, depending on your MPI library.

Comment: thanks for the answer. While this showed me the stuff regarding MPI, I still struggled a lot with the other libraries. The other answer showed me how to do it for the others to, so I accepted it.